# Using dynamic path in MongoDB aggregation pipeline with $getField operator

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

How can I use a dynamic path in my MongoDB aggregation pipeline to assign the value of 'address.city' to a field named 'fieldName' using the $getField operator? The current query I have doesn't seem to be working as expected.
Just a little note- I want to keep "fieldName" in order to calculate dynamically the path.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      fieldName: "address.city",
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      fieldValue: {
        $getField: {
          field: "$fieldName",
          input: "$$ROOT"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I don't think your desired implementation works. `$getField` doesn't suppose dot notation for object/array transverse. Also the value for `field` in `geField` cannot have the `$` dollar sign. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/#behavior

Comment: @YongShun
Hey, my implementation doesn't work, this is why I'm here :)
Do you know how I can achieve my goal? I didn't find a solution...

Comment: And I not understand why you need to complex your query. If you know what is the key field to be used for calculation, you can just use the `$`. Would be great if you can provide the complete context for your mentioned dynamic path.

Comment: @YongShun
I'm sorry for missing details.
The value inside "fieldName" is changing.
One time it can be "address.city" and in other times it can be "address.city", and so on.
I don't know the path, this is why I can't write in directly in the fieldValue, and this is why I want to keep it dynamic.

So, my question is how can I get the value of a field with dynamic path?

Comment: Are you using MongoDB driver such as Mongoose, MongoDB .NET driver etc? If yes and you are setting the field dynamically in back-end code, you can just make a string concatenation with `$`, for example: `fieldName: "$" + "<your field path>"`, and you don't need the `$getField` operator.

Comment: @YongShun
I created a sample, it will be easier to me to explain why I need, can you please take a look?
https://mongoplayground.net/p/zcTkBcZ1Hsk

In the example above, I need a way to get the value inside "fieldName" from the document

Comment: Most probably this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n5xT6jOrWpe) achieves your desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Write this as an answer from the comment as it resolves the Post Owner's question.*

Unfortunately, it is not possible to access the value as the field name in the `$getField` or other operator.

But what you can achieve is:

1. Convert the key-value pair to an array of objects consisting of `k` and `v` fields via `$objectToArray`.
2. Filter the matched object by matching the value of `k` via the `$filter` operator.
3. Convert the array of objects to a key-value pair via `$arrayToObjectt`.

```
{
  $set: {
    linkedStreets: {
      $objectToArray: "$linkedStreets"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "fieldValue": {
      $arrayToObject: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$linkedStreets",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.k",
              "$$steertType"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n5xT6jOrWpe)